# A kind of current mirror design

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-mirror

Recenlty I saw a kind of current mirror circuit used to provide bias current for a differential amplifier. The circuit is posted below and I don't understand its working mechanism, as well as the method to do specific design. Could anybody explain that for me? Thank you very much[image]

Comment: The circuit M1, M2, M4 and M5 is a **current refererence** circuit, I have designed a few of these myself. M3 is there to make sure that this circuit always starts up properly, without M3 it can get stuck in a state where all currents are **zero**. How this circuits works is described in many papers, go read: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/CMOS-Current-Reference-without-Resistance-Oguey-Aebischer/7a42c1c89748e9368a9bd6f5b82cebcaae94206c  also here: http://www.cse.psu.edu/~kxc104/class/cse577/11s/lec/S05BiasCkt.pdf

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, you can always invite the write to submit their comment as an answer and you can vote on it.

Comment: Got it. Could you please submit your comment as an answer? I thought it very helpful and I will vote on it.@Bimpelrekkie

Answer (score 1):

Bimpelrekkie (mostly) wrote on Jun 22, 2020 at 8:32 in a comment:

> The circuit M1, M2, M4 and M5 is a current refererence circuit, I have designed a few of these myself. M3 is there to make sure that this circuit always starts up properly, without M3 it can get stuck in a state where all currents are zero. How this circuits works is described in many papers, go read: [CMOS Current Reference without Resistance](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/CMOS-Current-Reference-without-Resistance-Oguey-Aebischer/7a42c1c89748e9368a9bd6f5b82cebcaae94206c) by H. Oguey and D. Aebischer or [this broken link](http://cse.psu.edu/%7Ekxc104/class/cse577/11s/lec/S05BiasCkt.pdf)

The OP requested that this comment be posted as an answer. I have marked it as a community wiki so that I don't receive reputation for the answer, which is not my own.